# Wordpress: Using the category slug get the category ID using mysql query

Tags: categories, mysql

basically, I have a cookie with the category slug stored, using this data I want to query the database and return the ID of the category.

I am new to mysql and this seems like an advanced query that may need to use joins, any help or guidance would be much appreciated.

Thank you!

Reference:
http://codex.wordpress.org/File:WP3.0-ERD.png

Answer (score 1):

Instead of writing custom SQL, you should be able to just use the native [`get_category_by_slug()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_category_by_slug) which will return a full [category object](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_category#Member_Variables_in_Returned_Objects) to include the category ID.

Comment: It is in a file completely separate from wordpress.

Comment: What is in a file completely separate from wordpress?